# Count "Mean" value from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to get the "mean" value of all Orders from my sharepoint list.

How do i do this?

This is my code so far:

```
function VisaLista() {
    namn = document.getElementById("txtNamn");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    "<View>" +
    "<Query>" +
    "<Where>" +
    "<And>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + namn + "</Value></Eq>" +
    "<Or>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Prioritet'/><Value Type='Text'>Hög</Value></Eq>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Startad</Value></Eq>" +
    "</Or>" +
    "</And>" +
    "</Where>" +
    "</Query>" +
    "</View>");
    listItems1 = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems1);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccessVisa, OnFail);
}
function OnSuccessVisa() {
    var listEnumerator = listItems1.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        $("#Kategori1").text(currentItem.get_item('_x0072_zb6'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and explain further what you want to accomplish and by what technique. Otherwise we may have to close this one as "Unclear what you're asking"

Comment: @BennySkogberg edited!